# Integral of a shifted function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I know the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.  However, how do I prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) dm(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-k)dm(x)$

I know in the case of the Riemann integral and pictures, the result is obvious as the area of the graph under the curve isn't changed by shifting.

Comment: A change of variable?

Comment: Try to prove that you can change variables using translation, that means Lebesgue measure is invariant under translations

Comment: Alright thanks, I will try it out.